# Slow connection with a Broadcom BCM4318 wireless card

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

I recently upgraded to 14.04. I just recently had an issue where my wifi wouldn't connect. I restarted the computer and it connected fine but now my wifi speeds are extremely slow. I saw a similar issue posted that said to use a script to provide info, which I've provided below. Where should I go from here?

http://pastie.org/9125814

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to enter the following command serveral times over a few minutes to find out at what rate you are connecting and whether it is the same or if it is changing.

```
iwlist wlan0 rate
```

Have you moved your system farther from the wireless access point since you upgraded?

Also the greater the distance or density of obstructions the lower the data rate.

Interference from other access points can also lower the data rate.

If the data rate is consistently good it might be a coincidence between the Ubuntu update and something going wrong in your path to the speedtest site, or something in your hardware. To eliminate these try a different speedtest location and a different computer.

Perhaps easier would be to test the non-coincidence case. Boot your computer from a 14.04 DVD and from a DVD for the last Ubuntu you were running and run the speedtest from each.

Comment: It's bouncing back and forth from 48 Mb/s to 54 Mb/s but that doesn't seem anywhere near accurate compared to Speedtest.net

Comment: Using Speedtest.net on my computer I get around 3mb/s download speeds. On my phone, standing at the same spot in the house, I'm getting 22mb/s down. I don't think it has anything to do with the upgrade.